# xslt split by delimiter

Tags: xml, xslt, delimiter, tokenize

I cant use tokenize (xslt 2.0)

I have a problem. I need to split a value "Test street\nStreet 2\nStreet3" based on a delimiter "\n" to produce

```
        <address1>Test street</address3>
        <address2>Street 2</address3>
        <address3>Street3</address3>
```

I have this so far:

```
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="ns0:sObject/ens:BillingStreet"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'\n'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <Address>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </Address>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Address>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </Address>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It gives me this:

```
        <Aaddress>Test street</Address>
        <Aaddress>Street 2</Address>
        <Aaddress>Street3</Address>
```

I tried using the position() but that wont work:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'\n'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <xsl:element name="Address{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="Address{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The above gives me:

```
        <Address1>Test street</Address1>
        <Address1>Street 2</Address1>
        <Address1>Street3</Address1>
```

Again, what I am looking is:

```
        <Address1>Test street</Address1>
        <Address2>Street 2</Address2>
        <Address3>Street3</Address3>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position()` is not really relevant here, as it returns the position of the currently selected node.

You will have to keep track of what iteration your recursive template is on by means of another parameter:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'\n'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1" ></xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <xsl:element name="Address{$pos}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="Address{$pos}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, you can slightly simplify your template, to avoid a bit of code duplication with creating the Address element; like so:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'\n'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1" ></xsl:param>

    <xsl:element name="Address{$pos}">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text, $separator), $separator))"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $separator)" >
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is not a string with new line character... use character reference `'&#xA;'`

Besides that, do note that `position()` function works against the current context list. That won't change after calling a named templated. So, your stylesheet fragment depens on other parts you haven't shown to us.

Comment: I was just playing with position(). Look at the one above. Thats the one I have.

Comment: Lets assume delimiter is "," for now.